# http.get through vpn + node

Tags: http, node.js, get

I want to be able to do a http.get request through node within my own vpn, but it seems likes the function is passing the website to a dns instead of look in my vpn. This following code works with google as the host.

```
http = require('http');
var host = "www.google.com";
var options = {host:host, port:80, path:'/'}

http.get( options, function( res ){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on( 'data', function( chunk ){
          console.log( chunk );
    });
});
```

but when I change host to a_site_on_my_vpn.com it throws a Domain name not found error, but when i type a_site_on_my_vpn.com on firefox I am able to load the page. I guess one way I can fix this is to find out the host name's ip but is there an easier way? :D

I resolve my own answer, but to answer the question in the follow up, the answer is yes here is a snippet that shows that, by doing an DNS ip lookup then going to google by IP.

```
var dns = require('dns');
var http = require('http');

dns.resolve4('www.google.com', function (err, addresses) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('addresses: ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));

    var options = {
    host: addresses[0]
    }

    http.get(options, function(res){
      console.log("Sending http request to google with options", options);
      var htmlsize = 0;
      res.on('data', function( chunk ){
          htmlsize+=chunk.length;
      });
      res.on('end', function(){
          console.log( "got html of lenght", htmlsize );
      });
    });
});
```

And this is the output

```
addresses: ["74.125.224.82","74.125.224.81","74.125.224.84","74.125.224.80","74.125.224.83"]
Sending http request to google with options { host: '74.125.224.82' }
got html of lenght 33431
```

Comment: Just curious, if you do have Node make the request using the IP instead of hostname, does it actually work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http` does resolve addresses correctly that are in a VPN, but I just had a small typo.